# Parsing an uploaded CSV file and storing data to database

Tags: php, upload, csv

I want the following functionality using php

I have a csv file. Each file corresponds to a row in my database

There is a html form that will allow me to choose the csv file.

Then once the form is submitted, I must parse the csv file and insert data into the db accordingly

How do I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading a CSV file can generally be done using the [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) function *(depending on your kind of CSV file, you might have to specify the delimiter, separator, ... as parameters)*

Which means that going through you file line by line would not be much harder than something like this :

```
$f = fopen('/path/to/file', 'r');
if ($f) {
    while ($line = fgetcsv($f)) {  // You might need to specify more parameters
        // deal with $line.
        // $line[0] is the first column of the file
        // $line[1] is the second column
        // ...
    }
    fclose($f);
} else {
    // error
}
```

*(Not tested, but example given on [the manual page of fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv) should help you get started)*

Of course, you'll have to get the correct path to the uploaded file -- see the `$_FILE` superglobal, and the section on [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php), for more informations about that.

And, to save the data into your database, you'll have to use the API which suits your DB engine -- if using MySQL, you should use either :

- [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli)

  - Note that you should prefer mysqli, instead of the old [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension *(which doesn't support features added in MySQL >= 4.1)*
- or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)

Comment: Noted should be that getting the uploaded file is to be done by `$_FILES['fieldname']`.