# PHP Parsing a CSV File

Tags: php, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing an uploaded CSV file and storing data to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454056/parsing-an-uploaded-csv-file-and-storing-data-to-database)

i have to add in my database a long list of data stored in a csv file.
In this file i have some usernames and their relative points.
What's the best way to get them?
Thanks
Matteo

Comment: Googling or searching SO for  `PHP parsing a CSV file` will answer your question fully and satisfactorily.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Explode each line and then store it.